# Add URL to homescreen

Tags: browser, launcher, nova-launcher

Can I somehow place a link to an URL to the homescreen without having to open it first?

I would like to place a `threema://` URL to the launcher -- of course, my browser won't show it long enough for me to choose any "Create shortcut" option, since it instantly opens Threema.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching: *Fennec Fdroid* can do that with a little detour. Create a bookmark for any page and then edit that bookmark -- you can then enter any URL you like. For the bookmark, you can create a shortcut on the launcher afterwards.